# Is it possible to load bootstrap modal directly with flask

Tags: flask

In flask we can render a page using render_template('home.html, data=data).
In the same way is possible to load bootstrap modal without having to use javascrpt?
For e.g if an element is clicked in the page,

```
<span class="example"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showExample" <a href="/showExample">Testing</a></span>
```

A call is made to function in flask function and it trigger the modal pop-up and pass data that can used to populate field

Answer (score 4):

If i'm understand what you mean, you can do this in JavaScript (just paste it in bottom of your page, in the tag "script":

```
document.getElementById('showExample').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Do some stuff, that you need to do...
});
```

Or, if you want, you can do this without JavaScript (i guess that you using Jinja2):

Insert it into your page template:

```
{% if show_example_modal %}
    <span class="example"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showExample" <a href="/showExample">Testing</a></span>
{% endif %}
```

Python view code:

```
@app.add_route('/something/')
def something():
    return render_template("something.html", show_example_modal=True)
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't make it clear but I was wondering if it is possible to do it without javascript

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm not sure how this is going to work because {% if show_example_modal %} will be part of something.html template ? It has to be two step process. 1. something.html will be loaded with it's data. It contains trigger for modal that will be loaded based on some data in something.html, so it need to fetch it's own set of data. In the above example all we are doing is when something.html is loaded, we are saying modal can be loaded too when clicked on 'Testing' ?

Comment: You can do the logic on the client side using JavaScript ***ONLY***, that's all.

Comment: yeah, I'm handling it that way already. Just wanted to make i'm not missing out on some aspect of jinja and flask :)